# Websocket reconnection loop, graphql_flutter

Tags: flutter, websocket, graphql

I am using `graphql_flutter` package in my app. This is the code for my client:

```
HttpLink httpLink = HttpLink(
    uri: 'https://*******/graphql',
  );
  WebSocketLink webSocketLink = WebSocketLink(
    url: "wss://*******/graphql/websocket/",
    config: SocketClientConfig(
      autoReconnect: true,
      inactivityTimeout: Duration(seconds: 30),
    ),
  );
  AuthLink authLink = AuthLink(
    getToken: ()async{
      print(await SharedPreferencesHelper.getAuthenticationToken());
      return "Bearer ${await SharedPreferencesHelper.getAuthenticationToken()}";
    }
  );
  Link link = authLink.concat(httpLink);
  link = link.concat(webSocketLink);
  client = ValueNotifier(
    GraphQLClient(
      cache: InMemoryCache(),
      link: link,
    ),
  );
```

However whenever I create a subscription like this:

```
client.value.subscribe(Operation(
      document: Subscriptions.chatMessageReceived,
      variables: {
        "receiverId": *******
      }
    )).listen((fetchResult){
      print(fetchResult.data);
    });
```

I get this log in repetition:

> Connecting to websocket: wss://******/graphql/websocket/... flutter:
>   Connected to websocket. flutter: Disconnected from websocket. flutter:
>   Scheduling to connect in 5 seconds... flutter: Connecting to
>   websocket: wss://******/graphql/websocket/...

Even though everything works fine in graphql playground. What can it be?

Comment: I'm also facing same issue, please let us know if any resolution.

Comment: @VarunKumar it was a backend issue. My backend used absinthe graphql library over [Phoenix Framework](https://www.phoenixframework.org/). If your backend is also the same, you can use [this](https://pub.dev/packages/absinthe_socket).

Answer (score 0):

this is because of inactivityTimeout: Duration(seconds: 30), in WebSocketLink config 
you can increase the Duration to prevent it from auto disconnecting.